# How to access Core Data generated Obj-C classes in test targets?

Tags: core-data, swift, xctest

I have a Core Data / Swift Cocoa application project in Xcode 6 (let's call the project `Stuff`). I created a Core Data entity called `Query` and used Xcode to create an `NSManagedObject` subclass for it.

At that point, Xcode 6 offered to create the bridging header for me, as expected, and created `Stuff-Bridging-Header.h`. Once I `#import "Query.h"` in the bridging header, then my model object `Query` is available in my app target Swift code.

How do I make that `Query` Core Data object (backed by the Xcode-generated Query.h and Query.m) available to my test target Swift code, `StuffTests`? I tried manually creating a header file `StuffTests-Bridging-Header.h` and adding `#import "Query.h"` to it, but my Swift test class is unable to resolve the `Query` class.

Comment: Are you using existing Objective-C code or is this a new 'Swift' project?

Answer (score 1):

I have a project with CoreData in pure Swift, no bridging header files and tests are working.
Here's how I've managed to do:

My project name is **cars** and I have a NSManagedObject called **Car**

Car.swift:

[image: Car.swift]

Car.swift file Target Membership:

[image: Car.swift file Target Membership:]

cars.xcdatamodeld Data Model Inspector:

[image: cars.xcdatamodeld Data Model Inspector]

Comment: Keep in mind: At the moment, Xcode 6.1 trips hard on the generation of subclasses with the app prefix making the correct method a pain. Instead of generating your entity subclasses, it'll generate a single "prefixed" class so you either need to use the "obj()" or generate subclasses without the prefix attached, then add it to the model.

Comment: I have the same structure but anyway, when I create an object and do the cast, the cast fails. This works: `var object: AnyObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Photo", inManagedObjectContext: context)`, but then this fails: `var photo = object as Photo`.

Comment: I finally managed to make it work: the `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName` method does not work but finding the entity then creating the object works. First step: `let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Photo", inManagedObjectContext: context)`, then `photo = Photo(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSManagedObject` directly in Swift as follows:

```
class Query : NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var attrOne : attrOneType
  // ...
}
```

Currently Xcode won't generate Swift code for an entity; it still only generates Objective-C which may lead you to a bridging solution.  But, you don't need to bridge - just start with the generated Objective-C and write Swift code, with the `@NSManaged` annotation.

Comment: I understand that and I'm fine with the Obj-C generated code. By importing Query.h into the bridging header, my `NSManagedObject` subclass `Query` is available in Swift, but only in my app target. I'd also like to use it in my tests and cannot figure out how to achieve that.

Comment: I don't have a bridging header in my app and core data works. But, tests using core data do not. Not sure why yet.

Comment: @DanielD but what should be imported in the tests bridging header? Because #import "Query.h" won't be found by the test target. Is it also necessary to update the Include Headers path to reference the app target's built headers? Something like this? $(CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR)/<AppTargetName>.build/DerivedSources

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to figure this out. The ideal solution is to import the bridging header in the test target itself. Go in `Build Settings` > `Swift compiler` > `Code Generation` and give the name of your bridging header. 
Be careful, the test target is not selected by default. You have to select it in the scrollbar (it's located on the same line as General, info, build Settings, build Phases, and Build Rules). 
This way, you will have the same bridging header for both your project and your different test targets.

Comment: But like zumzum, I have no bridging header and my app target works but my test target doesn't.