# How to test Core Data properly in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

There are quite a few subjects on this already, but I have yet to find a solution that is workable for Swift (Xcode 6.2).

To test Core Data backed classes in Swift, I generate new Managed Object Contexts that I then inject into my classes.

```
//Given   
let testManagedObjectContext = CoreDataTestComposer.setUpInMemoryManagedObjectContext()
let testItems = createFixtureData(testManagedObjectContext) as [TestItem]
self.itemDateCoordinator.managedObjectContext = testManagedObjectContext

//When
let data = self.itemDateCoordinator.do()

//Then
XCTAssert(data.exists)
```

The issue comes from passing a MOC created in the Test to the  class that's doing. Because entity classes are namespaced, Core Data won't fetch your the appropriate ManagedObject subclass and instead hands back a `NSManagedObject` set. When looping or doing anything with these objects (which in your class would be an array of test items (`[TestItem]`).

For example, the offending class `ItemDateCoordinator` would execute this loop (after pulling the relevant data from a `NSFetchRequest`)"

```
for testItem in testItems {
    testItem.doPart(numberOfDays: 10)
}
```

would result in:

> fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Also, I have come across a collection of information without much of a solid answer:

- To cast entities when creating them, I have been using a solution by [Jesse](http://www.jessesquires.com/swift-coredata-and-testing/), but that doesn't work on a larger scope of testing.
- A [solution has been posted on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26796530/205846) that involved swapping out the classes at runtime, but that hasn't worked for me with entity inheritance.
- Is there another method to testing your objects with Core Data in this case? How do you do it?

Comment: Are you facing a mocking problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was about to point you toward *Swift, Core Data, and unit testing* but see you've already found it. :)

That post doesn't elaborate much on where your files should exist (i.e., in which Target). You **should not** add `NSManagedObject` subclasses (or any files really) to *both* targets. I've found that this leads to all kinds hard discover bugs and cryptic errors.

And **definitely DO NOT** do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636888/swift-and-coredata-casting-issues-in-test-vs-non-test/26796530#26796530). That is a terrible hack.

Instead, make your classes public and `import MyAppTarget` in your `XCTestCase` files. Better yet, your model should be in its own framework as I mention in my recent [talk](https://speakerdeck.com/jessesquires/using-core-data-in-swift) (a video will be posted in a few weeks on realm.io). Doing this makes your models namespace very clear and generally easier to deal with. Then you'll need to `import MyAppModel` everywhere you access your managed objects.

I also have a new framework, [JSQCoreDataKit](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQCoreDataKit) that intends to make Core Data easier to use in Swift. One key part of this framework is the `CoreDataStack` which you can initialize using an in-memory store for your tests. There's demo app with examples, and well-commented unit tests.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer that finally got me to a solution (Xcode 7, Swift 2). Add your NSManagedObject subclass files to the main target only, not to the tests target. I found it not necessary to make them public (I think this is an Xcode 7 change). At the top of my test files I added: @testable import MY_MODULE_NAME.

Comment: Solved by using @testable import ModuleName as described here; https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-2-xcode-7-unit-testing-access/

Answer (score 4):

I believe this was updated recently (iOS 9/Swift 2.0) to have the testable keyword on an imported target, mean that the target's internal classes (the default) become public. From the docs:

[image]

So to add to jessesquires answer above, append @testable to your import, and this should solve the unit test errors:

```
@testable import MyAppTarget
```

Comment: +1 I have used your solution in a sample Swift 3.0 project (https://github.com/Daemon-Devarshi/MedicationSchedulerSwift3.0/tree/master/MedicationTests), it works seamlessly :-)