# Swift 2.0: Could not cast value MyApp.MyCustomClass to MyAppTests.MyCustomClass when using Set

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing, swift2

This is an error:

> Could not cast value of type `MyApp.Member` (0x1674daf8) to `MyAppTests.Member` (0x4c07248).

You can reproduce a bug in easy way:

1. Setup two `NSManagedObject`

   ```
   @objc(Member)
   class Member: NSManagedObject {
       @NSManaged var family: Family
   }

   @objc(Family)
   class Family: NSManagedObject {
       @NSManaged var members: Set<Member>
   }
   ```
2. Setup this also in your `.xcdatamodel`:
3. Then in your **TestFile**:

   ```
   func testA() {

       let family = Family.MR_createEntityInContext(context)
       let father = Member.MR_createEntityInContext(context)

       father.family = family

       let firstMember = family.members.first

       XCTAssertEqual(firstMember!, father)
   }
   ```

Comment: I suppose this is a problem with Swift's `Set`.

Comment: Do you redeclare `DBWorkingHours` in your test module? It seems to find that but not the right one. Do you import your app module?

Comment: Yes, above my test class I added both: `@testable import DirectBistro` and later `import DirectBistro`. Didn't help.

Comment: Then I suggest you report it as a bug

Comment: Hi, Bartłomiej! Could you post the link to your bug report please?

Comment: Of course, I could, but I do not know how to do this, since it is on my bureport accont... Any suggestions?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk could you post your project? Or a minimal working example?

Comment: @vrwim I changed the question to reproduce the bug in easy way

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Where do you get the `context`?

Comment: @vrwim Within `setUp()` I set: `context = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext()`

Comment: Looks like you have the class added to the test target directly which is duplicating it in runtime. No? `Member` should only be part of the app target, then the test target will use the correct class in runtime.

Comment: Of course, target membership of the `NSManagedObjects` is for both of them, otherwise it would be impossible to create an entity in test class, wouldn't be?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**I have found a solution:**

I suppose that those who has such problem, imported their files into test target this way:

[image]

Since they should do it just like this:

[image]

So, just remove the files from your test target. And then if you need your files within test target just use `@testable` keyword within your **every** test class.

[image]

This way there is no problem with casting values between targets anymore. It worked for me:-) Enjoy:-)

Read more from [Swift 2 + Xcode 7: Unit Testing Access Made Easy!!!!](http://natashatherobot.com/swift-2-xcode-7-unit-testing-access/)

Comment: You made my day. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm trying it on xcode 9.1 using swift 4 but it's not working. Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: Many thanks, I tried everything and found this by searching "could not cast value" ... yuh!!!

Comment: Please clarify which files you are referring to regarding Target Membership. I can't get the program to compile if I don't include the test target in the  xcdatamodel target membership.

Comment: I figured it out and got my tests working again. Swift is quite different than Obj C in that you don't include ANY of the project files in your test target. NONE. Just use the @testable import TARGET in your test and you'll have access to everything. Once I uncheck all of the product source, the tests returned to functioning correctly.