# Error in UnitTests Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing

Hi I'm doing UnitTests in my iOS Swift project, but after I run it says:

```
 Class Nurse is implemented in both ProjectName and ProjectName.Tests
 One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I found there's an error after every test case:

```
Could not cast value '<PROJECT_NAME>.<CLASS>' to '<PROJECT_NAME_TESTS>.<CLASS>'
```

I've tried to remove it from the Test build but it doesn't work, what should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you clean the project and build again?

Comment: Yes, I did it, nothing. :(

Comment: Right click the Nurse.swift file in Xcode and select "Show File Inspector".  Under Target Membership, uncheck (only) the checkbox corresponding to your test target.

Comment: This question may be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089389/swift-2-0-could-not-cast-value-myapp-mycustomclass-to-myapptests-mycustomclass