# XCTest .xib of custom UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib, xctest

How do you XCTest a .xib who's class is set to a custom class of type UIView?

I want to unit test this, and am thinking I need to instantiate the view (complete with IBOutlets) from nib, then test things like: `tempSearchCardView.titleLabel.text == "Hello World"`

I've tried `tempSearchCardView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SearchCardView", owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as? SearchCardView` but `tempSearchCardView = nil`

...

Here's my IB situation:

[image]

...

Here's my .swift file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here: [Swift 2.0: Could not cast value MyApp.MyCustomClass to MyAppTests.MyCustomClass when using Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089389/swift-2-0-could-not-cast-value-myapp-mycustomclass-to-myapptests-mycustomclass)

I tried most every other tutorial/advice I could find.

The above post says to remove the files from the test target, and simply `@testable import MyApp` ... then `testSearchCardView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SearchCardView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! SearchCardView` worked as expected!!!